# Firebase (GCP) cloud function run locally (nodejs 8) has EMPTY request query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I don't know what changed, but suddenly, when testing locally, my cloud functions (http, nodejs 8), has an empty object for req.query

This was working before

I have tried with nodejs 10 as well

The deployed version works fine, only the local one not

```
const REGION = 'europe-west1';
exports.test = functions.region(REGION).https.onRequest((req, res) => {   
 console.log('query', req.query); // prints [object Object] when run locally, even though query params are given   
 return res.json(req.query); // returns {} when run locally, even though query params are given 
});
```

I have tried both with **firebase serve** or **firebase emulators:start**

Another strange thing is, I can call

http://localhost:5001/aifinancegroup-dev/europe-west1/test?a=b

or

http://localhost:5001/aifinancegroup-dev/abc/test?a=b

Anything replacing abc works too